# If and else of javascript function are being executed at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking the value of a dropdown on load of the page. But when I debug, I see the controller is executing both `if` and `else` statements which is not supposed to be happening.

```js
  /* My code: */
  $(window).load(function() {

    if (($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() == 'Never') ||
        ($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() == 'Default')) {

      $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').hide();

    } else {

      $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').show();

    }
  });
```

I dont find anything wrong in the above code. Please help me find the problem in the above code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide the sample

Comment: you're missing a  ); at the end of the load method.

Comment: Edited the post. Missed it out while copying

Comment: I dont find any problem with this code,for me its executing the else statement only once.

Comment: If and else cannot be executed at the same time (at the same run, to be more precise). Your code probably runs twice. Put an alert in the if, another alert in the else, and a third alert after if-else and check the sequence of alerts. Or console.log("some message"), whatever suits you.

Comment: If you add console.log() lines inside the if and else do they both show up? My guess is the debugger is making it seem like it is going into the if, but it is not.

Comment: If I use alert then it is working as expected. If I remove the alert its not matching with the expected result

Comment: Use console.log with different messages inside if, inside else, after the whole if-else. And see the console output.

Comment: The code is working as expected only if have alert written in condition statements

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing this text:

```
$(window).load(function() {    
    if (($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").val() == 'Never') ||
        ($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").val() == 'Default')) {    
        $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').hide();    
    } else {    
        $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').show();    
    }
});
```